# How can I switch to Swift 4.0 in Xcode 9.3?

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode9.3

It seems like I have only options to go to 3.3, or unspecified:

[image]

Can I switch to 4.0 somehow?

Comment: I think, that u have to install the previous Xcode version.

Comment: Why? It’s very simple to migrate code from 4.0 to 4.1, the migrator can even do it.

Comment: @vadian, well tell this to Cuckoo and Mixpanel developers ;)

Comment: Well, then you have to wait with the Xcode update until all your dependencies are updated, too. You can also have both Xcode versions together in the applications folder.

Comment: did u fix that?

Comment: @iosMentalist, I just installed previous Xcode

Comment: damn! we should find something else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have updated xCode then under Build Settings, check the drop down options for Swift Compiler - Language.

Furthermore, 
You can download Xcode 8.x and 9.x from [Apple Download Portal](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/), if you've premium developer account (apple id). You can install & work with both Xcode 9 and Xcode 8.x in single (mac) system. (Make sure you've Command Line Tools supporting both version of Xcode, to work with terminal)

Comment: you can see the result of this actions on attached screenshot

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install swift 4.0 in XCode 10 with solution from here ["Switching Swift Versions inside Xcode using Toolchains"](https://medium.com/xcblog/switching-swift-versions-inside-xcode-using-toolchains-755b28831c43).

But in the end this **did not help**. I stuck on error:

> < unknown>:0: error: unknown argument: '-enable-batch-mode'

Even [disabling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52481653/4322841) not helped. I got:

> < unknown>:0: error: unknown argument: '-disable-batch-mode'

---

["Switching Swift Versions inside Xcode using Toolchains"](https://medium.com/xcblog/switching-swift-versions-inside-xcode-using-toolchains-755b28831c43) shortly:

1. Download desired [toolchain](https://swift.org/download/#snapshots), and click to install.
2. Select new toolchain in XCode Preferences.

   1. Select here:[image]
   2. Result here:[image]
3. Use desired swift, beware caveats.

---

Another related: [material](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43142147/4322841).