# How to get AWS frameworks working in Xcode 11?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, aws-sdk, aws-amplify

I'm trying to get AWS frameworks working in Xcode(version 11.2.1) by importing them **manually**. The only way I get them working is by adding them in the Embed Frameworks under Build Phases. Everything is fine until I import AWSMobileClient in one of my swift files. Here things go wrong. If I try to build project on device simulator I get this error:

```
Could not find module 'AWSMobileClient' for target 'x86_64-apple-ios-simulator'; found: arm64, armv7-apple-ios, arm64-apple-ios, arm, armv7
```

Then I change to physical device and I get this error:

```
Module compiled with Swift 5.1 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.1.2 compiler: /Users/lukacefarin/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Projects/InoSupport/AWSMobileClient.framework/Modules/AWSMobileClient.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.swiftmodule
```

I read about this error on [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58654714/module-compiled-with-swift-5-1-cannot-be-imported-by-the-swift-5-1-2-compiler) and it seems that I can't do much except waiting that AWS will fix that.

Is there any workarounds? All my project frameworks are imported manually so I don't want to use Cocoapods or Carthage.

**EDITED on 9 February 2020**:

I posted this [issue](https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/issues/2278) on GitHub and get replay that they are working on the solution. Till then use dependency managers I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem as you can see, my local swift version is 5.1.3.

```
"Incompatible Swift version - framework was built with 5.1 (swiftlang-1100.0.270.13 clang-1100.0.33.7) and the local version is 5.1.3 (swiftlang-1100.0.282.1 clang-1100.0.33.15)."
```

So, I had to look for aws-sdk-ios version compatible with my installed swift version 5.1.3.

Your installed swift version is 5.1.2.
During my tries, I found an aws-sdk-ios version compatible with your local version of swift 5.1.2.

**Try to use aws-sdk-ios "2.13.0", my log says that this framework was built with 5.1.2.**

```
*** Checking out aws-sdk-ios at "2.13.0"
*** Downloading aws-sdk-ios.framework binary at "AWS SDK for iOS 2.13.0"
***  Skipped installing aws-sdk-ios.framework binary due to the error:
"Incompatible Swift version - framework was built with 5.1.2 (swiftlang-1100.0.278 clang-1100.0.33.9) and the local version is 5.1.3 (swiftlang-1100.0.282.1 clang-1100.0.33.15)."
```