# Distribute Universal framework written in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, libxml2, dylib, abi

I'm facing the issue with distributing compiled swift framework. My framework heavily relies on the libxml2 dynamic library. In order to avoid issues with [Swift module compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58654714/module-compiled-with-swift-5-1-cannot-be-imported-by-the-swift-5-1-2-compiler), I've set build flag BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION = YES.

So I've used Xcode 11.3 Swift v5.1.3 to build my framework. I've integrated it into the Demo.app project. As being expected Demo.app works fine in Xcode 11.3.

However, I have another error trying to build Demo.app in Xcode 11.0 Swift 5.1.
I've got the error:

```
#import "libxml/HTMLparser.h"
        ^
/Applications/Xcode_11.0.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVSimulator13.0.sdk/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/HTMLparser.h:15:10: error: 'libxml/xmlversion.h' file not found
#include <libxml/xmlversion.h>
         ^
/.../DemoApp/ThirdParty/testXML.framework/Modules/testXML.swiftmodule/x86_64-apple-tvos-simulator.swiftinterface:6:8: error: could not build Objective-C module 'libxml2'
import libxml2
       ^
/.../DemoApp/AppDelegate.swift:11:8: error: failed to load module 'testXML'
import testXML
```

Here is the [repo with both framework and app projects](https://github.com/Parabak/libxmlIssue).

I'm using both Xcode version on the same Mac.

Comment: Is it important to you to be able to build on an older version if the new version works correctly? Am I misreading the question?

Comment: @TofuWarrior: let me rephrase it: it's important to me to distribute binary built on a latest swift version which is compatible with elder swift versions. Eg. built with swift 5.1.3 but compatible with 5.0.

Comment: @AliaksandrB. Were you able to fix this? I am stuck with the same issue :(

Answer (score 0):

Your project runs fine on my Xcode 11.3 tvOS simulator. However there's something I've noticed.
The framework you built only contains x86_64 architectures (simulator only), it won't work on physical devices.

For Xcode before 11.3 it seems like you need to add `$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2` and `${SRCROOT}/libxml2` to **Build Settings**. That fixed the issue for me on Xcode 11.2.1

Comment: Thanks for the response. I didn't create a fat framework, because it's just a demo. It works for me on Xcode 11.3 also, but it doesn't on earlier versions like 11.0

Comment: I reproduced and fixed your issue, please try on your side

Comment: Still doesn't work for me, could you please send me a link to the fixed Demo project? Thanks