# CompileSwiftSources normal x86_64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm relatively new to Xcode development. Essentially, the project that I'm working on uses the [PolarBleSdk](https://github.com/polarofficial/polar-ble-sdk) library which also has an RxSwift dependency. I added these as frameworks/compiled modules and both were working without error last week. Today I go to run my project and get the following error:

```
Module compiled with Swift 5.2 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.3 compiler: /Users/admin/eva-official/eva/eva/ios/PolarBleSdk.framework/Modules/PolarBleSdk.swiftmodule/x86_64-apple-ios-simulator.swiftmodule
```

I looked into the error on SO, found several of the same issue all with the same solution the most verbose answer is the following:

[Module compiled with Swift 5.1 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.1.2 compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58654714/module-compiled-with-swift-5-1-cannot-be-imported-by-the-swift-5-1-2-compiler/58656323#58656323)

So when I attempt this solution `BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION = YES;` I get this error:

```
CompileSwiftSources normal x86_64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    cd /Users/admin/eva-official/eva/eva/ios
    export DEVELOPER_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    export SDKROOT\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.0.sdk
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc -incremental -module-name Runner -Onone -enable-batch-mode -enforce-exclusivity\=checked @/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bqvaekbapdxicmavikgdqxwzdbni/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Runner.SwiftFileList -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.0.sdk -target x86_64-apple-ios12.4-simulator -g -module-cache-path /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -Xfrontend -serialize-debugging-options -enable-testing -index-store-path /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bqvaekbapdxicmavikgdqxwzdbni/Index/DataStore -enable-library-evolution -swift-version 5 -I /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bqvaekbapdxicmavikgdqxwzdbni/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bqvaekbapdxicmavikgdqxwzdbni/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F /Users/admin/eva-official/eva/eva/ios/Flutter -F /Users/admin/eva-official/eva/eva/ios -parse-as-library -c -j4 -output-file-map /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bqvaekbapdxicmavikgdqxwzdbni/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Runner-OutputFileMap.json -parseable-output -serialize-diagnostics -emit-dependencies -emit-module -emit-module-path /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bqvaekbapdxicmavikgdqxwzdbni/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Runner.swiftmodule -emit-module-interface-path /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bqvaekbapdxicmavikgdqxwzdbni/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Runner.swiftinterface -Xcc -I/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bqvaekbapdxicmavikgdqxwzdbni/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bqvaekbapdxicmavikgdqxwzdbni/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Runner-generated-files.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bqvaekbapdxicmavikgdqxwzdbni/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Runner-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bqvaekbapdxicmavikgdqxwzdbni/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Runner-all-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bqvaekbapdxicmavikgdqxwzdbni/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Runner-project-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bqvaekbapdxicmavikgdqxwzdbni/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -Xcc -I/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bqvaekbapdxicmavikgdqxwzdbni/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/DerivedSources-normal/x86_64 -Xcc -I/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bqvaekbapdxicmavikgdqxwzdbni/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -Xcc -I/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bqvaekbapdxicmavikgdqxwzdbni/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/DerivedSources -Xcc -DDEBUG\=1 -emit-objc-header -emit-objc-header-path /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bqvaekbapdxicmavikgdqxwzdbni/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Runner-Swift.h -import-objc-header /Users/admin/eva-official/eva/eva/ios/Runner/Runner-Bridging-Header.h -pch-output-dir /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bqvaekbapdxicmavikgdqxwzdbni/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders -working-directory /Users/admin/eva-official/eva/eva/ios

<unknown>:0: error: using bridging headers with module interfaces is unsupported
Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Other steps I've tried:

- Cleaning the build
- Removing `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`
- Restarting Xcode
- Building onto device

Comment: Additionally, the timing is important because I believe Xcode updated because when I rm -rf my project and reclone it warns to update config and the BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION option is not available, so suspect something in the update.

Answer (score -9, accepted):

For anyone stuck in this loop:
You have to wait for those dependencies to update to Swift 5.3, otherwise you have to stay on Xcode 11. In my case I updated to 12 during development.

You can download the previous versions [here](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/).

Answer (score 4):

Follow these steps

1. Clear de DerivedData folder

- rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

2. Clean Xcode project

- cmd + shift + k

3. Close Xcode project, maybe even reboot the mac (if you like)

Try again.
The first step was the crucial step for me, but step 2 and 3 could help as well.

Comment: for me since I am using React Native after clearing the DerivedData folder I also clear Pods, Podfile.lock, node_modules then start it again.

Comment: Reboot your Mac? Why not create your own IDE?

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem. The solution that worked for us was changing the architecture of the Terminal App. We switched from arm64 to -x86_64.

```
user@Mac-mini ~ % arch
arm64
user@Mac-mini ~ % env /usr/bin/arch -x86_64 /bin/zsh --login
user@Mac-mini ~ % arch
i386
```

Comment: This came up in my review queue and does not seem to have anything to do with the question at all. Can you please clarify or remove?

Comment: It may not be the answer to the original question but if you have issues with architectures this definitely helps.