# Compiler Error in CocoaPod File: unable to type-check, should use sub-expressions

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, compiler-errors, cocoapods

I just did the Update to Version 12.0.1 (12A7300). Then I got [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58654714/module-compiled-with-swift-5-1-cannot-be-imported-by-the-swift-5-1-2-compiler).

After setting the Build Libraries for Distribution option to Yes I got the error "The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions" :(

The error is in the LTEasing.swift file of [this cocoa pod](https://github.com/suzuki-0000/CountdownLabel) in line 26:
[[Screenshot of the problem code]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkpZb.png)

Its weird because this file always worked... only after the update it became a problem. I already restarted XCode and cleaned my build folder CMD+SHIFT+K.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: EDIT: I broke up the line of the podfile and it works now