# Facing issue integrating the ACSUICalling library to my project

Tags: ios, swift, azure, azure-communication-services

i am trying to integrate ACS to my app and facing this issue

> Failed to build module 'AzureCommunicationCalling'; this SDK is not
> supported by the compiler (the SDK is built with 'Apple Swift version
> 5.6 (swiftlang-5.6.0.323.62 clang-1316.0.20.8)', while this compiler is 'Apple Swift version 5.7.1 (swiftlang-5.7.1.135.3
> clang-1400.0.29.51)'). Please select a toolchain which matches the
> SDK.

it is working fine with another project

i tried adding 'AzureCommunicationUICalling', '1.1.0' to my xcode project with minimum deployment target 14.0 and expected to use it

Comment: perhaps try upgrading xcode to the latest?

Comment: could you please confirm which version of SDK are you using and min version of iOS?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to install both compilers (5.6 and 5.7) on the build machine and then check.

Users with a similar issue were able to fix the issue by following the steps outlined in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58656323/8194837). Quoting here for your convenience.

> “You need to set the Build Settings > Build Options > Build Libraries
> for Distribution option to Yes in your framework's build settings,
> otherwise the swift compiler doesn't generate the necessary
> `.swiftinterface` files which are the key to future compilers being
> able to load your old library.
>
> This ends up in your project.pbxproj file as:
> `BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION = YES;`

Please try the above steps and let us know how it goes.